# Creating a fake point light with empty object in the Unity shadergraph

Tags: unity, shaders, fragment-shader, unity-shader-graph

I'm trying to create a fake point light from an Empty object with the shadergraph. This is a Blender prototype of the effect i'm trying to create.

[image]

In Unity I do get the light mask to work somewhat as well if I try using a high poly mesh which is displayed on the right. However I want to use a normal map on a flat plane and there I start to get problems. This is the one one the left: the "light" direction looks pretty correct but I get this weird gradient filling the mesh if I move the empty object on it's Z axis.

[image]

This happens even if I swizzle the channels of the normal map around. I created the normal map in Blender with Raw color management.

[image]

Here is the shadergraph i'm trying to use, so I just get the Dot Product of the world position of the empty and the normal map. Am I doing something wrong with the graph or is my normal map messed up? Help, i'm a noob :)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried normalizing both inputs before taking the dot product?